# Skip first column in table loop in JS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run a loop over a table, which will have dynamic inputs, i.e its size will get adjusted as new data is added to the DB.
And I am trying to create a loop so I can add select tags to each cell of the table, other than the first row and first column (that are table headers).
I skipped the first row by using the `<tbody>` as a selector instead of whole `<table>`.
As for the first column, it's composed of `<th>` elements, so while doing my loop I tried to set a condition where it modifies only the `<td>` like this:

```
const body = document.querySelector('tbody');
for (let row of body.rows)
{
    for(let cell of row.cells)
    {
        if(cell=="<td></td>"){ //The problem is here I need a way to do this comparison
            const slct=document.createElement("select");
            slct.classList='custom-select';
            for (const shift of shifts) {
                let opt=document.createElement("option");
                opt.innerHTML=`${shift}`;
                slct.append(opt);
            }
            cell.append(slct);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: A preview of what I want to do]

Alas, It didn't work, can anyone help with how to do this? I looked it up but couldn't find something I can use.

Comment: A cell is not a string, and will most likely not automatically toString to it's `innerHTML` format.  You could try `cell.outerHTML` and see if that works.  But really if you want to skip the first cell, you need to just skip it, rather than trying to match against html

Comment: Use the index of the collection (perhaps in a traditional `for` loop) and skip index 0.

Comment: You could try cellIndex - `if(cell.cellIndex > 0)`

Comment: @Taplar I console.log the cells content and saw that it had this, `<td></td>` so I thought I could use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flag and use it to ignore first column for each row.

```
const body = document.querySelector('tbody');
for (let row of body.rows)
{  
   let isFirstColumn = true; // flag
   for(let cell of row.cells)
   {
       if(!isFirstColumn){
          const slct=document.createElement("select");
           slct.classList='custom-select';
           for (const shift of shifts) {
               let opt=document.createElement("option");
               opt.innerHTML=`${shift}`;
               slct.append(opt);
           }
           cell.append(slct);
       } else {
           isFirstColumn = false;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was looking for something like this at first, but couldn't get there, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the index of the collection (perhaps in a traditional for loop) and skip index 0.

This points out the idea by changing the background color of the columns other than the first column (all cells start out pink):

```js
const body = document.querySelector('tbody');
for (let row of body.rows)
{
    for(let i = 0; i < row.cells.length; i++)
    {
        if(i === 0) continue;
        row.cells[i].style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    }
}
```

```css
td {
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 background-color: pink;
 }
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I wanted to use that but I didn't know that the `cells.length `existed.

Comment: Glad to help! Have fun.